# When trying to integer encode string data using sklearn OrdinalEncoder, returning 0 for all categories?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

I have a dataset of many strings, and I want to convert them to integers for my keras model to use. When I try and use the sklearn ordinal encoder and I have tried sklearn one hot encoding, for all the categories only zeroes show up.
Heres some code-

```
X = dataset.astype(str)
oe = OrdinalEncoder()
oe.fit(X)
x = oe.transform(X)
```

and x[10] is just returning-

```
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: It has to do with your data `X` i think, can you share it or at least a portion of it?

Comment: unfortunately I cant share it, but its just a numpy array of strings, each row there are 97 columns. I have used sklearn's ordinal encoder before for working with similar data and it worked fine so im not sure on what the issue is here.